# error of calling cplex.dll from C# (4.0) .NET VS 2013 on win 7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I am trying to call CPLEX (a mathimatical optimizer) from .NET VS 2013 on win 7.

I have installed optimization.framework.

I have added

```
   using Optimization.Solver.Cplex;
```

in the code.

I try to run the example at:

```
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400073&aid=1
```

I commented out

```
//using ILOG.Concert;
//using ILOG.CPLEX;
```

It can be built. But, I got error:

```
  Unable to load DLL 'cplex100.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I change the DLL to cplex.dll but the same error. 
In

```
  using Optimization.Solver
```

when I typed ctrl+space , I can see that it includes many solvers, including CPLEX.

Why i got this error.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CPLEX, you need to install it. The DLLs that you need are related to the CPLEX version you install, so cplex100.dll is from CPLEX 10.0, cplex124.dll would be from CPLEX 12.4, and so on. It is a commercial licenced product, but academics can get free/cheap copies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate `cplex100.dll` in your installation and add an appropriate path to your project's linker properties – for your convenience: in detail described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Windows.html?lang=en).

Comment: I have never installed CPLEX100.dll in my machine. When I added "using Optimization.Solver.Cplex;", I thought that the CPLEX100.dll has been embedded in the visual studio. Now, I think I was wrong. I need to install CPLEX100.dll myself. visual studio only provides an interface for CPLEX100.dll, right ?